# Can't see raise messages in DBeaver or PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, dbeaver, raise

When i execute the function below (in the picture), i can't find the raise message anywhere even in execution logs: is there anyway to make it appear.

[image: picture of the function here]

script:

```
 SELECT helloworld('myname');
    
    
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION helloWorld(name text) RETURNS void AS $helloWorld$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
        RAISE LOG 'Hello, %', name;
    END;

$helloWorld$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

Messages with the level `LOG` typicall don't get sent to the client.

Either use `RAISE NOTICE` or set `client_min_messages` to `log`.

Answer (score 0):

also dont do a basic mistake like me that to see the `raise notice` messages inside function, you first have to call that function by `select public.helloworld()`